# Mocha test for response.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Suppose I've a function for rendering a page using response.render, how can I write a mocha test function to unit test this page.

For eg:

```
function getUsers(request, response)
{
 //reading request object
 //getting data from database based on request object
 //finally rendering the page:
   response.render{''users', {partials:{userData:data}
});
```

---

```
//mocha test function (not complete)
describe('users', function(){
    describe('#getUsers()', function(){
        it('It should render users listing page', function(done) {
            //?????
            //?????
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following

```
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');

response = httpMocks.createResponse();

sampleNodeModule.getUsers(request,response);

var responseData = response._getRenderView();
```

Comment: This just gets the name of the view I think.